# Rancher/HAProxy: https redirect not working

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, rancher

I have set up a HAProxy lb in front of my services.

According to the HAProxy documentation, in order to achieve `80` --> `443` redirect, the following line should be added to the

> Custom haproxy.cfg

tab when configuring the service:

```
redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
```

This does not seem to work since when I am accessing my site on `http://` it stays on `80`.

Any suggestions?

Using:

```
"CATTLE_RANCHER_SERVER_VERSION=v1.6.14"
rancher/lb-service-haproxy:v0.7.15
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that i resolved this, is the next:

- Add a new selector rule listening in the port 80 and HTTP protocol, put any what you want in target (foo=bar per example).
- Add this in the Custom haproxy.cfg tab

  ```
  frontend http-redirect
      bind *:80
      mode http
      redirect scheme https code 302 if !{ ssl_fc }
  ```